# How can i get some info on a Socket in socket.io version 4.x

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

As i upgraded to version 4.x of socket.io on nodeJs i run into issues with certain things breaking.
Here is 2 issues i am facing one is to get a list of all rooms a socket is part of. When i call
`socket.rooms` after a client is connected i get a correct response that list all rooms in a set.

Based on what i read using `io.sockets.sockets[536xdN11uf311xkFAAAD].rooms` but that gets me the below error.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'rooms' of undefined

How can i get the rooms for a given socket in 4.x

Also how can i get the socket info for a given socket without calling `io.sockets.sockets` then doing a for each on it to find the socket i am looking for.

Comment: From the doc, for a given socket, you use `socket.rooms` (which is a Set).  FYI, I don't think `io.sockets.sockets` has ever been a publicly documented interface.  Many have used it, but it's not in the doc and thus is not a committed part of the interface.

Comment: socket.io is a great product but the doc's suck and they change alot over new releases

Comment: I'm not a particular fan of the doc either, but it has improved recently and probably the reason you're having problems with `io.sockets.sockets` is that was never a public API and thus subject to change.  See my answer below for details using public interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i get the rooms for a given socket in 4.x

`socket.rooms` is a `Set` object that lists the rooms a given socket is in.  This is documented for socket.io v4.

If you have the socket.id instead of the socket object, you can do:

```
const sockets = await io.in(theSocketId).fetchSockets();
```

This will be an array of sockets, but if you passed in a socket id, there will be zero or one items in the array depending upon whether that socketid exists or not.  This is in the doc [here](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api/#namespace-fetchSockets) and is a fairly new way to do things.

So, putting these together:

```
async function getRooms(socketid) {
    const sockets = await io.in(socketid).fetchSockets();
    if (!sockets.length) {
         throw new Error(`socketid ${socketid} is not found`);
    }
    return Array.from(sockets[0].rooms);
}
```

Note: you will have deal with promises when using this interface (likely because of the support for remote adapters via redis or other clustered adapters).

Comment: Thanks, but this still doesn't answer me how i can get all rooms a socketid is part of

Comment: @SamS87 - Your question asked for a given socket, not for a given socketid which is why I didn't realize that's what you wanted.  Anyway, I've updated the answer to show you how you would get the socket from when starting with a socketid.

Comment: thanks that gets me way closer to what i am looking for as i now have the MAP Set(3) { 'HgeLKVTh76j0PvLyAAAD', 'test', 'demo' } for the rooms of socketid HgeLKVTh76j0PvLyAAAD. The only still i still struggle is to change set to an array i tried [...sockets[0].rooms] but that always gets me an empty array.

Comment: @SamS87 - `Array.from(set)` will turn a set into an array.  See [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) for `Array.from()`, though you can iterate a set with `for (let room of set) { ... }` just like you can an array because both support the generic iterable interface of ES6.